# Does JavaScript have expression-scope?

Tags: javascript, scope

The following code demonstrates an immediately invoked function expression used as the right-hand value for a default value in a destructuring assignment expression.

```
const { foo = (function bar() { return 'bam'; }()) } = {};
```

Function expression `bar` is not visible outside of the expression.

Does this mean JavaScript has expression scope?

If so, does this mean that the expression has its own conceptual `LexicalEnvironment`?

Comment: No. See https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-runtime-semantics-destructuringassignmentevaluation the production `AssignmentProperty : IdentifierReference Initializer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function expression `bar` is not visible because it's a *function expression*, even if a named one. It does not create any symbol for that function in the symbol table.

```
function bar() {}
```

This is a function declaration which creates a symbol `bar`.

```
(function bar() {});
```

This is a function expression which does not result in anything. It's a *named* function expression so you'd see a function name pop up in stack traces and the function can refer to itself by name, but it's not a function declaration.

Comment: So, function expression `bar`, does not impact the `EnvironmentRecord` of the outer `LexicalEnvironment` ("symbol table" in your answer). But given that the function expression will be given a `LexicalEnvironment` of its own when it is invoked, does that mean JS has expression scope or not? I can't figure it out. I would guess no?

Comment: AFAIK there's no such thing as expression scope in Javascript. What you have is simply not any sort of expression that creates any new symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and yes.

The [official spec for JavaScript](http://es5.github.io/#x10.2) even has a section talking about lexical environments.

At a high level, basically any closure or block will define a new level of scope, where functions aren't available outside of them. This is used to help provide scoping and do things like emulate "private" variables.

Comment: I do not believe this answer is correct (based on deceze' answer) although I cannot articulate why I think this!